# oracle sql error "ORA-00904:invalid identifier"

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have gone through all the questions relating to ORA-00904 and none of them seems to answer my problem. Here is the piece of shell command, I'm running and also works perfectly:

```
echo $(dzdo su - oracle -c '
    echo "DB1234" | . oraenv
    sqlplus -s /nolog << "hereDoc"
    CONNECT myUserName/"MyPassword"@DB1234
    select TABLESPACE_NAME from dba_tablespaces;
    hereDoc
')
```

But when I try to run the same command with a WHERE clause, the command fails with an invalid identifier error:

```
echo $(dzdo su - oracle -c '
    echo "DB1234" | . oraenv
    sqlplus -s /nolog << "hereDoc"
    CONNECT myUserName/"MyPassword"@DB1234
    select TABLESPACE_NAME from dba_tablespaces where TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TEMP';
    hereDoc
')
```

I have tried running the above command in various combinations only to get the very same error or even worse another error!:

```
1. select TABLESPACE_NAME from dba_tablespaces where TABLESPACE_NAME = q'[TEMP]';
2. select TABLESPACE_NAME from dba_tablespaces where TABLESPACE_NAME in ('TEMP');
3. select TABLESPACE_NAME from dba_tablespaces where TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TEMP' ;
```

These commands execute properly when directly running at the sqlplus prompt.

This seems to be pretty simple one but couldn't identify the case and I have already spent hours trying to fix this.

Comment: You probably need to escape the single quotes in `'TEMP'`

Comment: Unix, right? I don't remember Unix any more. Though, how about `where TABLESPACE_NAME = '"'"TEMP"'"';`

Comment: Can you also explain what this long series of the single and double quotes do, please. I do not have much of a unix/linux background. thanks